# How do I build a "jsonData" Object thats contain another string object "userIp"? I've to add the pass the jsonData object to pass the test

Tags: java, testng, rest-assured, builder, web-api-testing

This is my builder class:

```java
package org.jiraaf.data.builders.requests;

import net.datafaker.Faker;
import org.jiraaf.data.models.requests.OnboardingInvestorsRequest;

public class OnboardingInvestorRequestBuilder {
    private static Faker FAKER = new Faker();

    public static OnboardingInvestorsRequest getSingleUserRequest(String email, String mobile){
        return OnboardingInvestorsRequest.builder().countryCode("+91").email(email).isNri(String.valueOf(false)).mobile(mobile).userIp("").userId("8847fdb3-105d-4fe1-a8f5-c5d60b5485cd").build();
    }
}
```

This is my test case:

```java
private String generateToken() {
    Type type = TypeFactory.defaultInstance().constructParametricType(Response.class, UserSessionResponse.class, String.class);
        given()
                .contentType(ContentType.JSON)
                .body(sendOtpsRequest)
                .when()
                .post("/user/sendOtps")
                .then()
                .statusCode(200).body("status", is(true));

        Response<UserSessionResponse, String> UserSessionResponse = given()
                .contentType(ContentType.JSON)
                .body(singleUserRequest)
                .when()
                .post("/user-sessions")
                .then()
                .statusCode(200)
                .extract().as(type);

        return UserSessionResponse.getEntity().getToken();
    }
}
```

This test is erroring out saying  "invalid request" since the json data object is not passed in the request.

How can I fix this?